# How to pass javascript variable in ajax django url

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

```
   <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    // type: 'GET',
                    url: "{% url 'size_reducer:data_delete' id %}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('ok');

                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to pass id in ajax URL but it is giving me an error
because it's not getting id

Answer (score 2):

You can use Template literals to pass Javascript variable

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  // Can use django url if using <script> tag inside template
  url: `{% url 'size_reducer:data_delete' ${id} %}`, 
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
     console.log('ok');
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use django url tag in ajax like this.
your url should be something like

```
url: "/<path_to_data_delete>/" + id
```

So first save the id in javascript variable and append the variable to url string as per your declared url.

Remember not to use the domain name before /<path_to_data_delete>.
If you are running site on local server, skip the domain name. i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: suppose id is my javascript variable, how can I access the javascript variable inside the ajax